# URL rewrite not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using the following code in .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([^\./]*)[:;,\.]*$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_,-]+)/([0-9]*)$ listing.php?business=$2
```

1. This code hides the .php extension of the PHP files in the root folder only, But I want to apply it to the PHP files in all subfolders.
2. I also want to deny access using the original URL , that is the URL includes the .php extension.
3. I also want the third rule should be worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_,-]+)/([0-9]+)$ listing.php?business=$2 [L,QSA]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s\?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: When entering the original URL , that is the URL includes the .php extension, this redirect to the same page. But I want to send a "Page Not Found-404" error when entering such URL with ".php"  extension.

Comment: This is working, But I want one more modification: When entering the URL "www.domain.com/some_text/" or "www.domain.com/A_DIRECTORY_NAME" redirect to listing.php. I dont want it, redirect only if entering "www.domain.com/some_text/A_NUMBER"

Comment: Iam using this code in htaccess   `ErrorDocument 404 /error_docs/404.php` ,  It is working except for *.php URL. When entering *.php URL I found this message: `The requested URL /eds.php was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`             And when I tried by removing this line `RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]`  It works fine.

Comment: In that case you can use: `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` that will give forbidden message.

Comment: Then Shows this message:  `Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /eds.php on this server.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: Forbidden error is because of `F` flag but you probably have `ErrorDocument 500` also that you should comment out.

Comment: Right, this you need to comment out.

Comment: the issue still remains

Comment: tail your Apache error log and see what error you're getting.

Comment: `[Wed Jul 31 14:58:52 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: This is due to infinite looping. You might have some other code in .htaccess causing this infinite looping.

Comment: These are the only other codes:
`DirectoryIndex home.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error_docs/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error_docs/500.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error_docs/403.php
Options -Indexes`

Comment: Difficult to debug it remotely. You can try commenting out all `ErrorDocument` lines.

Comment: When commenting all `Errordocument` lines ,  shows `403 Forbidden` message. I want the error document to be displayed.

Comment: ok now just uncomment `ErrorDocument 403 /error_docs/403.php` line

Comment: `Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /login.php on this server.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34531/discussion-between-hyder-ali-and-anubhava)

Comment: It is working, I used `RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]` instead of `RewriteRule ^ - [F]`.  Still it is woking fine!

Comment: Yes `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` is the key.

Comment: when entering an URL like `www.domain.com/a_folder_name` automatically converted into `www.domain.com/a_folder_name/`. How to avoid it

Comment: Trailing slash is not being added by above rule. Request you to post a new question and leave a comment here, I will post an answer after investigation.

Comment: Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand this comment.

Comment: The stack overflow banned me from asking questions

Comment: Oh ok then you can register a new account and post question.

Comment: I got it - `DirectorySlash Off`

Comment: How to get the rewritten URL of current page without query string?      $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']  will give it but it does not support in all servers.  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] give it, but it includes query string

Comment: Please answer my new question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872756/how-to-get-current-rewrited-url-excluding-querystring