# PHP how to get current rewrited URL excluding querystring?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am using the following URL rewriting in .htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\&_,-]+)$ business/business_home.php?business_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\&_,-]+)/(about)$ business/business_about.php?business_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\&_,-]+)/(products)$ business/business_products.php?business_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\&_,-]+)/(enquiry)$ business/business_enquiry.php?business_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\&_,-]+)/(contact)$ business/business_contact.php?business_id=$1 [L,QSA]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s\?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Then How to get current rewrited URL excluding querystring?
For eg: From the page having URL:        `/22/somestring/enquiry?value=5&page=9&item=coffee`
I expect:    `/22/somestring/enquiry`

I tried with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but it return `/22/somestring/enquiry?value=5&page=9&item=coffee`
And also `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` give me what I expected, but  it generates an `Notice: Undefined index: REDIRECT_URL` in some pages. And also [it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5493174/2050886) in some servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you PHP you can use code like this to get current URI **without query string**:

```
$thisuri = preg_replace('/\?.*$/', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Comment: if ( isset($_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]) ) ,   $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"] itself generate current URI without query string. Then why use preg_replace

Comment: You can skip `preg_replace` in first if. Let me edit.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot quotes around regex. Try it now.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: REDIRECT_URI

Comment: oh sorry it is `REQUEST_URI`. Corrected now. Try it.

Comment: see my question **it doesn't work in some servers.**

Comment: **READ MY COMPLETE ANSWER AGAIN** and then prove how and where it didn't work for you.

Comment: You are Right.  Then  **$thisuri = preg_replace('/\?.*$/', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])** itself is sufficient. Am I right?

Comment: is **$thisuri = preg_replace('/\?.*$/', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])** itself is sufficient ?

Comment: Yes that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe PHP has a superglobal for the URL without a query string, but you can manually strip the query string out:

```
protected function stripQuery($str){
  return preg_replace('/\?(.*)/', '', $str);
}
```

Comment: See the question. $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] give me what I expected. Isn't it a superglobal